# Reverse DNS lookup not resolving correctly

Tags: smtp, spam, reverse-dns

I've been searching and searching for the answer and I can't find it.

My problem is that all of my emails sent from my server are either going to spam folders or not being delivered. I am trying to apply for jobs, but I can't do that if all of my emails are being sent to spam folders.

I have no idea how to fix this, and I can't find answers.

I know that it is a reverse DNS issue because when it does the reverse DNS lookup it doesn't find my domain name. I have a VPS through Corespace, the reverse lookup finds their propagation.com site. I don't know how to adjust that, do I need to contact them to have the IP point to my domain, or because there are a lot of domains pointing to that IP do I need to change my smtp information to reflect that address.

I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 1):

Your VPS provider will control the reverse DNS for your server, and so you will need to contact them to make any changes to it.

Comment: Okay. Would I get the same result if I used a different smtp client and just changed the reply-to address?

Comment: Your email address isn't really the issue. It's the server's name matching by both forward and reverse DNS that needs to happen.

Comment: Damn.  See I was with a VPS company and they weren't charging me for the space, but they sold my account to corespace and they haven't charged me yet either, but I'm worried that if I message them they'll start charging me and I can't afford it right now.  I'll have to wait and fix this issue later, when I have a job and can pay for it.